# TinyMCE - Como transforma-lo em campo requerido?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, tinymce

Estou a utilizar um campo de `TextArea` com o `TinyMCE` para postagem de textos e gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar alguma validação para que ele não aceite valores em branco.

Já tentei adicionar o `required` do `HTML5`, mas quando tento enviar o post, o campo não envia e também não exibe o erro, estando preenchido ou não.

**html**

```
<textarea type="text" name="texto"></textarea>
```

**script tinyMCE**

```
  <script src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.js"></script>
   <script>tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        height: 245,
        theme: 'modern',
        plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
        'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
        image_advtab: true,
        language : "pt_BR",
   forced_root_block : false,
   force_br_newlines : true,
   force_p_newlines : false
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Seria possível adicionar a parte do código referente ao que está a tentar fazer?

Comment: Você pode fazer a validação via javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso penso que não basta apenas adicionar um `required` no HTML.
Terias que criar um código algo deste gênero:

```js
$('#enviar').click(function(){
   if($('.requerido').val() == ''){
      alert('O textarea não pode estar em branco!');
   } else {
      // Envia dados
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="requerido"></textarea>
<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: A resposta está perfeita, obrigado. Porém, me campo não é um button, é um input do tipo submit. Quando disparado, o formulário mostra o alert, como o campo vazio ou não, e mesmo assim envia os dados em branco. Como agir?

Comment: Adiciona um `else` ao código e chama a função responsável por enviar os dados dentro do `else`. Assim caso o campo estiver vazio, ele mostra o alert, senão (`else`) chama a função e envia os dados. `if($('.requerido').val() == ''){ alert('O textarea não pode estar em branco!'); } else { //chama a função que envia os dados }`.